# Jquery Datatables MakeEditable select/delete error

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am working with a data table that is formed with HTML and also sAjaxSource then MakeEditable is applied to edit it. But running into a problem were the moment the data table loads it displays the error (there is only one row in result set so not sure if that could be something).

This is error I get:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$(".table-action-deletelink", oTable).live')
```

Here is my HTML code, its inside a bootstrap tab.

```
<button id="btnDeleteRow">Delete</button>
          <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="info">
            <p>
                <table id="user_info_table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>User ID</th>
                                <th>First Name</th>
                                <th>Last Name</th>
                                <th>E-mail Address</th>

                            </tr>
                        </thead>

                </table>
            </p>
          </div>
```

Here is the data table:

```
var oTable2 = $('#user_info_table').dataTable({
            "fnRowCallback": function( nRow, aaData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                  $(nRow).attr("id",aaData.id);
                  return nRow;
             },
        "bDestroy": true,
        "bAutoWidth": false,
        "bProcessing": true,
        "bDeferRender": true,
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "sAjaxSource": '/info/user_info_data/' + sData['id'],
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "id", "sName": "user_id"},
            { "mData": "first_name", "sName": "first_name"},
            { "mData": "last_name", "sName": "last_name" },
            { "mData": "email", "sName": "email" },
        ],
             "fnInitComplete": function() {
                    this.fnAdjustColumnSizing(true);

                    },

        }).makeEditable({
            sUpdateURL: "/info/update_ajax/",
            sDeleteURL: "/info/delete_ajax/",
            fnOnCellUpdated: function(){

            }
        });
```

Here is JSON response from AJAX call:

```
{"aaData":[{"id":"5","first_name":"John","last_name":"Lee","email":"jlee@yahoo.com"}]}
```

I can see the data on data table being displayed but the moment it shows up it shows that error in console. I investigated a bit and saw that its looking for a class called .table-action-deletelink this is for inline deleting but I don't want that thus created button.
https://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/wiki/DeleteRecord

Any help would be appreciated thx.

Comment: how about this one: https://github.com/mindmup/editable-table

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hmm, got it working in this [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/luuSHNGTJqFK0j9P7p2Y?p=preview).

Only thing I have changed are the .live eventhandlers in jquery.datatables.editable.js to .on since they are deprecated since jquery 1.7.

So i turned all three occasions of

```
$(".table-action-editlink", oTable).live("click", function (...
```

to:

```
$(".table-action-editlink", oTable).on("click", function (...
```

Maybe this is giving you the error, since its directly related to your error message.

Use my patched version of the jquery.datables.editable.js from the plunker and give it a try if you are using jquery >= 1.7.

Uh, forgot: Of course the actual ajax calls for updating/deleting do not work in this plunker since i can't do server sided processing there:-)

Update:
If you want to highlight the selected row a bit add this to style.css:

```
table.dataTable tr.row_selected {
  background-color: #C9DDE1;
}
```

Note that this might collide with other css definitions.

Comment: that totally got rid of error thx! But do you know how can i get the select working? When i click on the row i would like it to select row and change color and highlight row thx

Comment: great find, thanks. Would not have known that either